# unity3d model rises on play

Tags: model, unity-game-engine, motion

(I know I have a bad choosing-answer record, but I will definitely select a good answer from now on.)

Unity3d problem:

My terrain and car both have rigid bodies that use gravity.

When I push play it looks like the scenery/island falls away or either the car rises.  Since the transform y-coordinate changes when the car rises, I'm assuming it's the car that is flying away.  It is supposed to stay on the cement ground.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Clarification:  it looks like the car's Y stays constant and the rest of the world falls away.

Comment: Weird thing that I don't understand:  The X-Y-Z box that indicates where a model is is way below the car.  The car was has a neon green ring around it with a line coming up from the button to meet where it is at the center.  I don't get this.  Shouldn't the box be where the model car is?

Comment: Also, when placed above ground, the car starts flipping and goes upwards on play.

Comment: Sorry, the y values of the car do diminish.

Comment: Weird, it doesn't rise when I turn of Wheel Collision, but it doesn't fall to the road,either.

Answer (score 1):

Your ground should not have a rigidbody, this will cause it to start falling through the world space and your car with it. Have you tried just placing a collider on the ground?

Answer (score 1):

The terrain shouldn't have a rigid body or use gravity enabled. It will fall until it hits something else with a collider (and there's likely nothing below the terrain). Remove the rigid body on the terrain then assess other problems.